# How can I use rollapply with a 5 month window?

Tags: r, zoo

I noticed this in the documentation of `rollapply()` to roll by 3 days:

```
## rolling mean by time window (e.g., 3 days) rather than
## by number of observations (e.g., when these are unequally spaced):
#
## - test data
tt <- as.Date("2000-01-01") + c(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10)
z <- zoo(seq_along(tt), tt)
## - fill it out to a daily series, zm, using NAs
## using a zero width zoo series g on a grid
g <- zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "day"))
zm <- merge(z, g)
## - 3-day rolling mean
rollapply(zm, 3, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA)
```

Suppose I have the following data:

```
data.zoo <- read.zoo(
                data.frame(
                    date = sample(seq(as.Date('2001-04-12'), as.Date("2019-04-05"), by="day"), 600), 
                    val = runif(1:600), 
                    val2 = runif(1:600)
               ))
```

Is it possible to somehow use `rollapply()` with a 5 month rolling window to calculate the rolling mean of `val`? The problem with a 5-month rolling window is that the number of days in a month varies...

NOTE: I would prefer a base-R solution but other libraries would be interesting to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since width can be a vector of widths, one for each row of the input, we can simply compute the number of days between each date and 5 months prior and use those numbers for the width vector:

```
library(zoo)

ym <- as.yearmon(time(data.zoo))
w <- as.Date(ym) - as.Date(ym - 5/12)
r <- rollapplyr(data.zoo, w, mean, fill = NA)
```

Alternately we could write `w` like this with lubridate.

```
library(lubridate)
w <- time(data.zoo) - (time(data.zoo) %m-% months(5))
```

### Update

If there can be missing dates then

```
library(lubridate)
w <- sapply(time(data.zoo), function(x)
  length(intersect(seq(x %m-% months(5), x, "day"), time(data.zoo)))
```

or repeat this replacing `%m-% months(5)` with `subtract5m` which does not use additional packages:

```
subtract5m <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) == 1) seq(x, length = 2, by = "-5 month")[2]
  else as.Date(sapply(x, subtract5m))
}
w <- sapply(time(data.zoo), function(x)
  length(intersect(seq(subtract5m(x), x, "day"), time(data.zoo))))
```

Note that due to the ambiguity of the definition of 5 months ago the various computations for w may vary slightly based on slightly different assumptions.

Comment: I was thinking, couldn’t this be re written using yearmon?

Comment: Good idea. Have added.

Comment: You're assuming that the days are consecutive and that is a failure in my example. What if they weren't consecutive (as generally we deal with business dates)? Just as an improvement on this, what if some months were missing? (I've modified my example to show this)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to get the yearmon approach to work with missing dates?

Comment: See Update.  The second computation  does not use yearmon but it does avoid using additional packages.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on G. Grothendieck's ideas I went with:

```
  ym <- as.yearmon(time(data.zoo))
  ym.cutoff.ideal <- ym - 5/12
  ym.cutoff.closest.to.ideal <- as.yearmon(time(data.zoo)[findInterval(as.Date(ym.cutoff.ideal), as.Date(ym)) + 1])
  w <- time(data.zoo) - as.Date(ym.cutoff.closest.to.ideal) + 1
  r <- rollapplyr(data.zoo, w, mean, fill = NA)
```

It looks like it is working correctly...